# how can test ionic project with laravel api in android?

Tags: laravel, ionic-framework

I want to test  Ionic with Laravel API project on my android device. My computer and my android device are in the same network.

if I inspect with chrome error, I am getting

> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED or ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.

I added cors middleware in Laravel API and I am working in localhost.
Can you help me? How can connect devices and localhost?

Comment: there must be a firewall preventing outside connections

Comment: how can i get it? @alimfazeli

Comment: What your setting in cors for allowed origins?

Comment: in my cors is;      public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, 
    OPTIONS'); @MihirBhende

Comment: What IP you are hitting? Is  that local network IP accessible to you?

Comment: I am using  127.0.0.1 or Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:IPv4 is it problem? @MihirBhende

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is the local ip. You need to check the IP address of the server machine on which APIs are running

Comment: @MihirBhende yes in cmd I wrote ipconfig  and i tried IPv4 but still same problem.

Comment: Lets say in ipconfig's IPv4 you get `192.169.10.2`. Can you try that IP on  the same server machine. Sometimes the external 80 port is blocked in LAN configuration so you can not access it by LAN IP

Comment: yes 192.169.10.2:8088  is workingbut 192.169.10.2:8000 is not working.My api port is 8000.How can solve this LAN problem? @MihirBhende

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem on friday... the problem was I was calling the API with http://blablabla... and CORS demands to call it https://blablalba (note the S of SECURE...)

It happen that I have the SSL Certificates on the API Server, I don't know if that's a requirment altogether...

Comment: you added SSL Certificates on the API Server and your problem solved .am I correct?

Comment: NO! I already had SSL Certificate... I don't know if that's the problem, I just told you because I think maybe it is... Try adding the 'S' even if you don't have ssl, and tell me what happened...